# System of 3 linear Equations Involving 3 Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is a good book to learn how to solve System of 3 Linear Equations Involving 3 Variables, this is for an university exam admission. I have found links on the web but I would like to grab a book and read about it.

Comment: Now that that's been cleared up, any good book on linear algebra will do. I recommend any of the MIT OCW materials on the internet as web resources and for books, Gilbert Strang is amazing at introducing new concepts, also I recommend my undergraduate text Linear Algebra: Concepts and Methods by Martin Anthony.

Comment: Your description is a little vague. You should clarify whether you want to learn about linear algebra or high school level algebra. Three equations and three unknowns are covered in either course.

Comment: it is high school level algebra since is for university exam admission